# same data-attributes for different element (html5 and jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to have two elements with the same data-attributes?

HTML

```
<div id="cerchi" class="container">

       <div class="row">

          <div class="col_6 clearleft">
             <div class="blu" data-link="nadir.php">
                <p>1</p>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col_6 omega">
             <div class="arancione" data-link="sole.php">
                <p>2</p>
             </div>
          </div>

       </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#cerchi .col_6 > div").click(function(){
   alert($("#cerchi .col_6 > div").data("link"));           
});
```

If yes, why if I click on the second "div" the alert gives the result "nadir.php"? instead of "sole.php"? do i something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps it is your JS code, which is not shown.

Comment: sorry i had forgotten it

Comment: Your JS has two results, you are only alerting the first. try a .each() loop and you'll see.

Comment: You have a logic issue with your selector. Think about what that selector does for a moment, forgetting the fact that it is inside a click event handler(because that doesn't matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's looking for the first match.  Change

```
$("#cerchi .col_6 > div").click(function(){
   alert($("#cerchi .col_6 > div").data("link"));           
});
```

to

```
$("#cerchi .col_6 > div").click(function(){
   alert($(this).data("link"));           
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! especially for the speed at this time! I have yet to practice with jquery, i'm sorry :)

Comment: @Andrea - Everyone starts somewhere and this is one of those things that isn't necessarily obvious.